# jquery datepicker doesn't automatically close in modal dialog once selected

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using jQuery 2.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.11.1. If the jQuery dialog is non-modal, then the date picker is dismissed automatically once a date is selected. However, if the dialog is modal, then the datepicker still stays open even once a date is selected.

This only happens with IE 10, not with Chrome or Firefox. Anyone knows how to fix this?
Here is my simple HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#showDialog").click(function(){
            $("#mydate").datepicker();
            $("#newdialog").dialog({modal: true});
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="showDialog">Show Modal Dialog</button>    
<div id='newdialog' style="display: none; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <h5>Test DatePicker in modal dialog</h5>

    Enter name: <input type="text" id="myname" />
    <br />
    Select date:<input type="text" id="mydate" />
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```